# JOOQ -> Convert alias to datatype

Tags: java, kotlin, jooq

I have a query that returns a field of type array, and I used .as('Names'), to give it an alias.
Now I need to assign this to a class.
How can I convert the AliasField to datatype MutableSet?

I tried doing:

```
 myClass.names = record.get("Names", MutableSet::Class.java)
```

But this is of type mutableSet<*>! , I'll need to convert it a nullable type to MutableSet?.

Answer (score 2):

Just keep a reference to your field expression and use that to read values from the record, e.g.:

```kotlin
val names = MY_COLUMN.as("names")
val record = ctx.select(names).from(...).fetchOne()
myClass.names = record.get(names)
```

Comment: That field is a subquery of type `jooqService.using(txn).select(DSL.asterisk(),  DSL.array(select table.name from table where ...) as "Name" ....)` .
When I do record.get("names"), It loses the type.

Comment: It's hard to answer a *specific* question when you generalise and simplify. Why not ask the complete question with all the details instead? I can certainly help, but if I have to guess, I'll guess wrong (or not specific enough). In any case, the concepts are the same.